# Creating an image sequence with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a way to animate a series of images, preferably with javascript/jQuery.
What I would like to do is to make some sort of a counter that renames my source image onClick.

Each click (back/forth) triggers the next series of images.

So during a certain time interval
`<img src="01.jpg" />`
replaces
`<img src="02.jpg" />`
replaces
`<img src="03.jpg" />`

etc.

So the images following up eachother rapidly look like an animation :)

I hope i've made myself clear, any help would be highly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Just look up online. There are already **many** examples of this.... ***What have you tried?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy to understand way of accomplishing whats you want is positioning all images at the same place and showing only one at a time...

```
var images = $('img.slideshow'),
    nextStep = function(i) {
       images.hide().eq(i).show();
       setTimeout(function(){
             nextStep((++i)%($('img.slideshow').length));
       },1000);
   };
nextStep(0);
```

This is a very easy way of showing the animation

Comment: This will go on **FOREVER** `0 % any number === 0`

Comment: Ever heard of `++i`? :-P

Comment: @Neal It's getting late, I better take a break ;)

Comment: Oy... I fixed it **for you** :-P

Comment: And Now I fixed it **even more** :-D

Comment: Thanks for the effort guys, I will give it a try. I'm an absolute beginner so I didn't know what to look for exactly.